# Laravel query with hasmany relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm new to laravel so forgive me for the possible noobish question. Also, I did look into all the other 'similar' questions but either they're don't reproduce the right solution or i'm honestly having a hard time wrapping my head around it.

The scenario:

I have a Post model and a Subject model. This is what they look like at the moment.

in Post.php

```
public function subjects() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Subject', 'posts_subjects');
}
```

in Subject.php

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Post', 'posts_subjects');
}
```

Now, what i need to achieve is:

In case an query parameter is passed to the request(ie q=Food) i want to return only the posts that contain the subject food in their subjects relationship and none of the others. if nothing is passed, then i just show everything...

This is what my PostsController's index action looks like atm.

```
public function index() {

    $q = Input::get('q');

    $posts = Post::all();

    return View::make('posts.index', ['posts' => $posts]);
}
```

How would i go about doing that? would greatly appreciate some help.
Thanks a lot

PS. I'm able to get all the posts with this code.

Comment: I think you may be a bit confused on how the relationships are working.  Can a single Post have many Subjects (Can a single post be associated with Food and with Travel) ?

Comment: A many-to-many relationship utilizing a pivot table is meant to use `belongsToMany()` on both sides of the relationship.

Comment: Yes, sorry. i did(and do) have belongsToMany on both models.. i just changed things a around a bit thinking i might be doing something wrong but the issue remains.. i can get the posts for a given subject from the Subject model but since its the PostsController we're talking about, it feels weird to base the entire return value on a different model..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested code, but it probably will work for you, if you have only one Subject returned by that query:

```
public function index() 
{

    if($q = Input::get('q'))
    {
            if($subject = Subject::with('posts')->where('name', $q)->first())
            {
                $posts = $subject->posts;
            }
            else
            {
                $posts = array();
            }
    }
    else
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
    }


    return View::make('posts.index', ['posts' => $posts]);
}
```